# Is this step mathematically allowed?

Tags: integration, limits

In my signal and systems course, my professor claims that the energy of a signal $x(t)$ over an infinite and continuous time interval is:
$$
E_{\infty}=\lim _{T \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-T}^{T}|x(t)|^{2} d t=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|x(t)|^{2} d t
$$
My concern is about the substitution of $\infty$ in place of $T$ before evaluating the integral. Is this always correct or is it mathematically more correct to evaluate the integral then compute the limit?

Comment: Look back at the *definition* of $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$ - there's less here than meets the eye!

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Improper_integrals

Comment: Thank you so much I think my question was embarrasing and hence I will delete it oh but before I do, I noticed in the wikipedia page that they said this is an abuse of notation to replace the upper bound with a $\infty$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many people write $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x(t)|^2dt$ as $\lim \limits_{T \to \infty} \int_{-T}^{T} |x(t)|^2dt$ because they believe that using infinity as a number is not proper, so they write it as a limit. However, since $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x(t)|^2dt = \lim \limits_{T \to \infty} \int_{-T}^{T} |x(t)|^2dt$$

is true, that must mean that the converse,
$$\lim \limits_{T \to \infty} \int_{-T}^{T} |x(t)|^2dt =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x(t)|^2dt $$

is true as well.

Comment: Thank you very much